# Protobuf repeated message option

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm trying to append some documentation metainformation to a protobuf message by extending google.protobuf.MessageOptions. One of my metainfo option may appear more than once. Looks like I can declare repeated option but how can I use it on a message?

Here is an example of what I try to achieve:

```
extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions {
    optional string description = 51234;
    repeated string usages = 51235;
}

message MyMsg {
    option (description) = "MyMsg description";
    option (usages) = ???

    optional bool myFlag = 1;
    optional string myStr = 2;
}
```

What should I type instead of ??? if I want fo document two different ways of usage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you can specify a repeated option multiple times:

```
message MyMsg {
  option (description) = "MyMsg description";
  option (usages) = "usage1";
  option (usages) = "usage2";

  optional bool myFlag = 1;
  optional string myStr = 2;
}
```

**Edit**: the way to access repeated field is not documented and took some time to look throug headers so I decide to add it to this answer:

```
auto opts = MyMsg::descriptor()->options();
std::cout << opts.GetExtension(description) << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < opts.ExtensionSize(usages); ++i)
    std::cout << opts.GetExtension(usages, i) << std::endl;
```

Comment: What about repeated options? How to set them?

Comment: Sorry, I've meant "repeated composite options".

Comment: @GillBates Ah... I'm actually not sure if those are possible to express, but it's been a very long time since I wrote that code. It might be possible to write them in TextFormat (in {} braces)?

Comment: @GillBates according to documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#customoptions), the syntax for that is:

message Bar {
  optional int32 a = 1 [(foo_options).opt1 = 123, (foo_options).opt2 = "baz"];  
  // alternative aggregate syntax (uses TextFormat): 
  optional int32 b = 2 [(foo_options) = { opt1: 123 opt2: "baz" }]; 
}

Comment: @danbars, wow the alternative syntax is indeed works! Where it is described? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: @danbars, I don't see anything like that here:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec

Comment: @GillBates custom options are part of proto2 spec, and not proto3. The reason is that it uses extension which is not supported in proto3 anymore.
So even if you generally use proto3, you still have to define your custom options in proto2 format.
Therefore, the documentation for this is not in proto3 docs, but in proto2. I gave the link to this above, here it is again: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#customoptions
look at the last example of the section before "generating your classes"